# Event when PhoneApplicationPage exits

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I handle the event when a PhoneAppplicationPage (eg. MainPage.xaml) exits?

I tried handling Unloaded event but that doesn't get called when I exit the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean this event :

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        // write exit logic
    }
```

This event is called whenever you navigate away from a page, whether by pressing the back button or the home button. Just paste the above in the code behind class of your page and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. I was looking at PhoneApplicationPage event handlers, and did not know there are these methods that I can overwrite. Still a newbie to WP7. Thanks.

Comment: Nope! This working when user ALREADY navigated from page. And more, OnNavigatingFrom called when page unloaded. 

So, instead of that you should using OnBackKeyPress for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by exits? You can handle the event when the user presses the back key by subscribing to PhoneApplicationPage.BackKeyPress.

Example:

```
private void OnBackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (messageBoxResult != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However when the user exits the application by pressing the home button, search button, a toast notification, incoming call or similar it is called tombstoning. You can handle the Deactivated event on the App to save a state in your application so that you can resume where the user left off the next time the app is started. But you can't "stop" the tombstoning - so that the user cant exit the application.

Read more about tombstoning here:
[Architecting WP7 - Part 5 of 10: Tombstoning by Shawn Wildermuth](http://wildermuth.com/2010/10/17/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_5_of_10_Tombstoning)

Comment: By exit I mean navigating away from the page. Thanks for your solution, but OnBackKeyPress does not cover the case when a user press the home button.

Answer (score 0):

when a PhoneAppplicationPage ( MainPage.xaml) exits,
this is like form closing event,
`MainPage_PointerExited` event works in `wp8.1`.

Even though this thread is 4 years old, I want to answer in case that
may be helpful to others who look for the answer.

```
Private Sub MainPage_PointerExited(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.PointerExited

    Application.Current.Exit()

    'your code goes here

end sub
```